# Receiving "InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11" during websocket.send

Tags: java, javascript, websocket, jetty

I am getting this error:

```
DOM Invalidate exception 11
```

From following code but I cannot find the cause.

```
/*This is little bit pseudo stylish coded so might have some 
syntax errors */

    var socket;
    var client = {
        connect: function(){
            socket = new WebSocket(mylocation);
            socket.onopen = this.open;
            socket.send = this.send;
        },
        open: function(){
            this.send("Sent from socket open function");   //works
            socket.send("Sent from socket open function");  //works
        },
        _send: function(){
            socket.send("Sent from send function");     //error
            this.send("Sent from send function");       //error
        }
    }

    client.connect();
    client._send();

    ----- ERROR DESCRIPTION --------
    //DOMException {message: "InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11", 
    //name: "InvalidStateError", code: 11
```

I am currently using Java Jetty Websocket for the server.  What does this error mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have infinite recursive function:

```
send: function(){
    socket.send("Sent from send function");     //error
    this.send("Sent from send function");       //error <--
}
```

Comment: It's not the problem. I changed send to _send but it still doesn't work =(

Comment: Only current solution I found is passing around this (context) of .onopen evenlistener method.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, this error typically means the server is busy / or that existing websocket connections are blocking, and are not allowing new websocket connections. I'm not familiar with Jetty, but I get the same error with a server consisting of uWSGI+gevent -- which allows at most one websocket connection at any given time -- when a second browser tries to connect before the existing connection is closed, it gets precisely this error.